# Auto input "yes" in Azure cmdlet

Tags: powershell, input

im not a dev, so please excuse the silly question,
I have a simple powershell script I need to run to stop a vm in a scale set. The script is correct when run in powershell, but fails in automation runbook because it asks for a "yes" input.
How on earth do i add a "y" to this script?

```
#variables
 $ResourceGroupName = '<rgname>'
 $VMScaleSetName = '<scalesetname>'
#script
Stop-AzVmss `
-ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
-VMScaleSetName $VMScaleSetName `
-InstanceId "1" `
```

i tried every incorrect variant of "yes" in the script :)